# core-nlp's SUTime Timex3 value differs from the GUI output

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, sutime

I was trying to use the 'SUTime' functionaly from core-nlp. If I try to use this from the online demo for a 'sampleInput'

```
From next month, we will have meeting on every friday, from 3:00 pm to 4:00 pm.”
```

which results in  (with reference date: 2017-1-1):

```
<TIMEX3 range="(2017-02-01,2017-02-28,P1M)" tid="t1" type="DATE" value="2017-02">next month</TIMEX3>
```

But, when I try to run the same input through SUTime API, it results in (esp: 'Temporal Value')

```
<Token text="next month" Temporal Value="THIS P1M OFFSET P1M" Timex="null" Timex type="DATE" Start offset="5" End Offset="15" />
```

Below is the code:

```
List<CoreMap> timexAnnsAll = document.get(TimeAnnotations.TimexAnnotations.class);
                for (CoreMap cm : timexAnnsAll) {
                    try {
                        List<CoreLabel> tokens = cm.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class);

                        Temporal temporal = cm.get(TimeExpression.Annotation.class).getTemporal();


                        System.out.println("Token text : " + cm.toString());
                        System.out.println("Temporal Value : " + temporal.toString());
                        System.out.println("Timex : " + temporal.getTimexValue());
                        System.out.println("Timex type : " + temporal.getTimexType().name());
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you don't have the doc date set.

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeAnnotations;

import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;

import java.util.*;

public class SUTimeExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Annotation document =
        new Annotation("From next month, we will have meeting on every friday, from 3:00 pm to 4:00 pm.");
    document.set(CoreAnnotations.DocDateAnnotation.class, "2017-03-01");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    //props.setProperty("customAnnotatorClass.time", "edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeAnnotator");
    //props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,time");
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,entitymentions");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    for (CoreMap entityMention : document.get(CoreAnnotations.MentionsAnnotation.class)) {
      if (entityMention.get(CoreAnnotations.EntityTypeAnnotation.class).equals("DATE")) {
        System.out.println(entityMention);
        System.out.println(entityMention.get(TimeAnnotations.TimexAnnotation.class));
      }
    }
  }
}
```